# How can I set a web server in a specific directory in OSX Mavericks?

Tags: macos, apache

I am running a web server in OSX Mavericks using the default directory location (`$HOME/Sites`). How can I add sites from distinct arbitrary directories ?

I have found instructions about [how to change the root folder of the apache server](http://brianflove.com/2013/10/23/os-x-mavericks-and-apache/), but I do not want to override the default location (I have things there) but to add new folders.

Comment: You will need to modify the /etc/apache2/http.conf file -

Answer (score 5):

This might be overkill, or answering a slightly different question than you asked, but if you have [npm](http://nodejs.org), you can

`npm install http-server`

and then just

`http-server`

from the directory you want to host. http-server will reply with the path hosted and the port it is hosted on e.g.:

`Starting up http-server, serving ./foo on port: 8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server`

If you launch multiple instances it will increment the port.

Comment: I had not thought about using something else than Apache (already installed). Maybe I should give it a try to npm. Could you please expand a bit your answer ? How can I access the server at that location ? (I already have the apache server running in port 80). Is it easy to shutdown the server for the directory where I started ?

Comment: yep. I added a bit. It tells you the port to use and how to shutdown. Just leave that terminal window open and you can quit it whenever you are ready.

Comment: You can install node (which includes npm) using homebrew, if desired, via "brew install node".

Answer (score 5):

The easy way (python):

```
$ cd some/dir
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

The slightly less easy way (apache):

Use apache virtual hosts. Here is a guide http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/. Basically, it allows you to point apache to multiple directories (they can be located anywhere).

It goes something like this:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Uncomment this line

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Edit the vhosts

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

There should be an example in the file, you can just edit that to fit your needs. Here is an example.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin me@example.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/USER_NAME/Sites/test.com"
  ServerName test.com
  ErrorLog "/Users/USER_NAME/Sites/test.com/error.log"
  CustomLog "/Users/USER_NAME/Sites/test.com/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

When you want to add another site, copy those lines and append them to the bottom of the file (changing the settings for your new site)

Lastly, edit your /etc/hosts file so you can access your new site.

```
$ sudo emacs /etc/hosts
```

Add this line

```
127.0.0.1 local.test.com
```

Restart apache for the changes to take effect.

```
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

Since you said that you wanted to keep the default site, add an entry into the vhosts file that looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /Users/USER_NAME/Sites
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart apache.